# Is it possible to automate running PDFelement using command line

Tags: windows, command-line, automation, command-line-arguments, pdf-scraping

I am currently trying to parse some PDF with tables to formats like csv/excel so that I can then programmatically process them with python, etc.

I have found that PDFElement does a good job converting PDF to excel, but have only been doing conversions manually via the GUI.

I'm hoping to be able to automate the process of batch converting PDF to excel using a program and was wondering if anyone had any ideas on how to best achieve this.

My initial instinct was to try to run the program .exe from command prompt using some arguments. However, based on their support page, [it doesn't look like this functionality is supported.](http://forum.pdf.wondershare.com/index.php?/topic/1659-library-for-developer/#comment-5558)
Is there a way around this? Or should I resort to some sort of automated clicking script? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

PDFelement cannot be used from the command line. Their software provides a GUI and there is no way to automate tasks. I've spoken with their support.